# What can class 0 message (flash SMS) do to Android devices?

Tags: security, sms

I'm using a Samsung phone and I recently got an anonymous message via Class 0 Message

[image: heres the picture]

> **Class 0 Message**
>
> URGENT MATTER ,CONTACT
>   ME MY EMAIL NOW
>   (email redacted)
>
> From: (phone no. redacted)

I saw a concerning article regarding the issue, it said that it can apparently reboot your phone? Is that true?

What I did was I responded to the email not knowing it might be a scam.

Comment: Do you have any antivirus installed on the smartphone? [Protect Yourself from “SMiShing”](https://www.mcafee.com/blogs/consumer/family-safety/protect-yourself-from-smishing)

Comment: I don't have one but I'm downloading mcafee

Comment: Don't what it means I'm pretty new regarding any phone issues, didn't even know you can get attacked by a simple SMShing

Comment: @NeoAragones, please, add on your question *full device description*.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to install a good antivirus, on Google there are free good antivirus like [AVG](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antivirus), [Avast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity) and the like. Then, try to full scan on your device looking for some [malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware) and don't forget to full scan the sdcard too.
2. If after made the step 1 succesfully you still are getting that SMS message, so I highly recommend you to **[factory reset](https://www.androidauthority.com/factory-reset-android-1119937/)** your device, which one means that your device *go back to the factory settings* and all the data stored on the device will be deleted except the sdcard data (of course, if you didn't encrypt the sdcard).

**Important:** if you factory reseted your device, pay much attention when installing apps again, check out apps are really *trusted*.

References:

- [The best antivirus software for
  Android](https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/mobile-devices/)
- [Don't Answer Text Messages of This Type. It May Be a
  Scam](https://www.inc.com/joseph-steinberg/do-not-answer-text-messages-of-this-type-it-may-.html)
- [Malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware)
- [How to factory reset Android
  devices](https://www.androidauthority.com/factory-reset-android-1119937/)